# "Link Assemblies" task failed unexpectedly issue while App build in Release Mode Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, release

Getting the following issue while trying to build App Release Mode in Xamarin Android.
Why is it appearing and how can it be resolved?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State Error
>
> The "Link Assemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>
> Xamarin.Android.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Reference to
>   metadata item 'System.Void
>   Android.Widget.TextView::SetTextAppearance(System.Int32)' (defined in
>   'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null') from 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be
>   resolved. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve
>   System.Void Android.Widget.TextView::SetTextAppearance(System.Int32)
>
> at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
>     at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
>     at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
>     at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext&
>   context)
>     at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
>
> ---End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at Xamarin.Android.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException,
>   String message, Object[] args)
>     at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
>     at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() MyApp.Droid         Build

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue, debugging worked fine until that error came up.

Restarting VS didn't help.
Changing the `Solution Platform` did the trick.

Comment: For me, it had to do with an earlier warning, NU1605, about a detected package downgrade. That was unintentional, so after editing the csproj file to use the correct version, suddenly the Release build no longer complained about a failure to resolve System.Void

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue in by changing the `Target Android Version` and setting the `Java Max Heap Size` in the following manner.

[image]

> 1. Right click MyApp.Droid
> 2. Properties > Android Options > Advanced (tab)
> 3. Set 'Java Max Heap Size' to 1024m

Comment: @Adel Have u tried increasing the java heap size to a larger value?

Comment: Doesn't help :/

Comment: Right ans 

or even you can check it on 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/android-linkassemblies-error/


check  this reference

Comment: Try to change  'Java Max Heap Size' to 1G
P.S it's capital G

Answer (score 3):

Try this configuration for Debug mode
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, that fixes it by disabling the linker. Which is not the expected behavior. so it's not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I got this too after upgrading to Xamarin Forms. You need to make sure your Target Framework is the last version.

Answer (score 2):

After updated xamarin version i start getting this error.
Clean project first then build it again. fixed for me. Rebuild not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check Mono android subfolder in Xamarin.forms package folder, sometimes linking to old Mono android version. Change it to new. It worked for me.
I changed from Monoandroid 8.0 to Monoandroid 9.0 of some dll's like Xamarin.Android.Platforms etc..