# Xamarin Android LinkAssemblies task failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Using *Visual Studio 2017* Preview **15.4.0** and the latest updates to everything as of today.
Whenever I build my project I get this *error*, as a workaround I have been turning linking to 'none' as suggested nearly everywhere, but this isn't a fix, and I would really appreciate some useful advice on what I can do to be able to publish this app the way it is supposed to be. The error is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>   Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void
>   Android.Support.CustomTabs.Chromium.SharedUtilities._MobileServices.CustomTabActivityHelper::LaunchUrlWithCustomTabsOrFallback(Android.App.Activity,Android.Support.CustomTabs.CustomTabsIntent,Android.Net.Uri,Android.Support.CustomTabs.Chromium.SharedUtilities._MobileServices.ICustomTabFallback)'
>   in assembly: 'Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.dll' --->
>   Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void
>   Android.Support.CustomTabs.CustomTabsIntent::LaunchUrl(Android.App.Activity,Android.Net.Uri)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference
>   reference)    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference
>   reference)    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)    at
>   Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)    at
>   MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext&
>   context)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   res)    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() com.tapig.ria.quickmeme C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Preview\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   1591

I cannot remove this package as it is required by the *Facebook*. *Android SDK* wrapper client, but I also can't have my app size increased because of this issue, any ideas welcome.

EDIT: If I enable Android 4.4, which debugs perfectly on a device, I get this error too, under the same heading.

```
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Acr.UserDialogs.Fragments.AbstractDialogFragment`1::OnKeyPress(System.Object,Android.Content.DialogKeyEventArgs)' in assembly: 'Acr.UserDialogs.dll' ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: instruction
   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.InstructionOffset..ctor(Instruction instruction)
   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadScope(ScopeDebugInformation scope)
   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadScopes(Collection`1 scopes)
   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadScope(ScopeDebugInformation scope)
   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadScopes(Collection`1 scopes)
   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadScope(ScopeDebugInformation scope)
   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadDebugInfo()
   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadMethodBody()
   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadMethodBody(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition.<>c.<get_Body>b__41_0(MethodDefinition method, MetadataReader reader)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Read[TItem,TRet](TRet& variable, TItem item, Func`3 read)
   at Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition.get_Body()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() com.tapig.ria.quickmeme C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets 1591
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit, my head is all over the place today, appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.dll` is being referred from a different location in the android project references. Changing that will fix your issue.

Comment: In the targets file? Out just generally in the project?

Comment: I have 2 entries in packages config, and that is the only place in the solution that it appears, as far as I can search and see: 
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />

Comment: As per this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177430/link-assemblies-task-failed-unexpectedly-issue-while-app-build-in-xamarin?rq=1) I have tried those solutions, setting linking to none does solve the problem, but it is not a fix, and app size is an issue. Thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: any ideas where I should be looking? I can't find any extra references.

Comment: Although there was not enough information in the answer to allow me to resolve the issue I have marked the answer as correct due to lack of interest.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, though the reason went from Xamarin.Auth library. By default, it automatically resolved to Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs v 23.3.0. The fix was to manually add higher version to Android project (as of now it is 26.1.0.1).