# Link Assembly task failed while building Xamarin Android project in Release mode

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to build Xamarin.Android(Native) project in release mode but am not able to build the project. Below is the error that I am getting.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error     The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006:
>   Could not resolve reference to 'Android.App.Job.JobServiceEngine'
>   (defined in assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') with scope 'Mono.Android,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'.
>   When the scope is different from the defining assembly, it usually
>   means that the type is forwarded. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException:
>   Failed to resolve Android.App.Job.JobServiceEngine    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference
>   reference)    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference
>   reference)    at
>   MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)    at
>   MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)    at
>   MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly(AssemblyDefinition
>   assembly)    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize()    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)    at
>   Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)    at
>   MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger,
>   LinkContext& context)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   res)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception
>   innerException, String message, Object[] args)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   res)    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

I also tried solution mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177430/link-assemblies-task-failed-unexpectedly-issue-while-app-build-in-xamarin) SO post but still the same error.

Comment: You should post your build and linker options

Comment: @Dishant, do you have any updates on this issues?

Comment: @WeiLoonWong Sorry, this an old post and I don't know the exact solution that worked for me. I guess repairing Visual Studio did the work.